# Multiple classes on one element in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm having trouble defining multiple classes on one element. To be specific - something is wrong with the tss:

```
".right": {
    layout: "horizontal"
},
".right.top-right": {
    width: "50%"
},
```

Element with classes `right` and `top-right` isnt' 50% wide

Comment: i do not think you can add multiple classes in titanium alloy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do something like this in your tss file:

```
".right":{
    layout:'horizontal'
}
".top-right .right":{
    width:'50%'
}
```

Or just do this:

```
".right":{
    layout:'horizontal',
    width:'50%'
}
".top-right":{
    width:'50%'
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one must be work with double class

```
    <div class="nameClass1 nameClass2">
//your content here
</div>

.nameClass1 {
layout:horizontal;
}

.nameClass2 {
width:50%;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you have divs in this.  This is tss not css. Consider deleting your answer